# Source of April O'Neil's psychic powers

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, april-o-neil

In about season two or three of the new 2012 series April O'Neil shows abilities of psychic powers. If she is human where does she get the power from?

Comment: Season two or three of which series? Have you checked Wikipedia for plot summaries?

Answer (score 2):

She's not wholly human. Her mother was 'experimented on' while she was pregnant which evidently included injecting her with Kraang genetic material.

> **Donnie:** *Based on all the info I've culled from the clone lab, your cellular makeup is actually a morphogenesic blend of human and Kraang DNA.*
>
> **April:** *Wait. Are you saying-?*
>
> **Donnie:** *You're not entirely human, April. That's why you have psychic powers. In fact, you are a half-human, half-alien mutant.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNMT: Eyes of the Chimera](https://tmnt2012series.fandom.com/wiki/Eyes_of_the_Chimera)</sup></sub>